# Vim joining lines during wraping

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am using `formatoptions` to format my files. But if I have a new line character in my tex file, Vim joins the lines, removing this character. How to define in Vim the hard wraping without joining lines?

**UPDATE:**

I can observe this when I execute the following commands

```
ggVGgq
```

Comment: That's what that sequence of commands is _supposed_ to do. If you want to wrap lines longer than 'textwidth' without joining any lines, use this instead: `:g/./normal gqq`  That will execute the `gqq` (format this line) command on each line in your file individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to `formatoptions`. It is because you execute formatting on the whole file. To avoid joining you need to execute it on each line alone. For this you can use the following command:

```
    :%normal gqq
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `a` and `w` in your `'formatoptions'` setting?  If so, try this:

```
:set formatoptions-=a formatoptions-=w
```

See:

```
:help fo-table
```

Comment: This is the line from my `vimrc` `set formatoptions=t`.

Comment: @user14416: Unless you have `a` in your 'formatoptions', Vim does not join lines unless you tell it to. Since you don't have `a` in your 'formatoptions', you, or one of your plugins, is telling Vim to join those lines. To discover what is happening so that your lines are not joined when you don't want them to be, we need more information, including an example of the actual text you are editing and *exactly* what you are doing when you observe the lines being joined.

Comment: @Heptite See my update.

Comment: @Heptite I tried the same sequence of commands with `vimrc` of one line `set fo=t` and the same result. So it is not plugins.

Comment: To whoever voted this answer down, that was really uncalled for and I hope you'll reconsider. Heptite provided a reasonable answer. It's not his fault that the question was next to impossible to answer correctly at first given the lack of information in the original version. He should not be penalized for making a good attempt.